Sending an email to a phone number gets broken up on the phone
I've been tasked with sending a text message in a program. I got it to send ok using Net.Mail and a list of email-endings by phone carrier, but the text on the phone is broken into 3 parts when received.
My code is as follows:
'Email Customer
Dim strTo As String = ""
If Customer.NotifyByEmail Then
    strTo = Customer.Email
End If
If Customer.NotifyByText Then
    If strTo <> "" Then
        strTo &= "," & Customer.PhoneNumber & Customer.PhoneEmailEnding
    Else
        strTo = Customer.PhoneNumber & Customer.PhoneEmailEnding
    End If
End If

If strTo <> "" Then
    Using oMailMsg As New Net.Mail.MailMessage
        Using SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient With {
            .Host = "mail.server.com",
            .Port = 587,
            .DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            .EnableSsl = True,
            .Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("programs@email.com", "#####")
        }
            Dim sFrom As New Net.Mail.MailAddress("programs@email.com")
            oMailMsg.From = sFrom

            If strTo.Contains(","c) Then
                Dim arMultiTo As String() = Strings.Split(strTo, ",")
                For Each strCurTo As String In arMultiTo
                    Dim sTo As New Net.Mail.MailAddress(strCurTo.Trim)
                    oMailMsg.To.Add(sTo)
                Next
            Else
                Dim sTo As New Net.Mail.MailAddress(strTo.Trim)
                oMailMsg.To.Add(sTo)
            End If

            oMailMsg.Subject = "Your Surfboard Repair Has Been Picked Up"

            'Build the message body (text only)
            oMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = False

            oMailMsg.Body = "This message is to notify you that the board you dropped off for repair has been picked up by the repairman. Your contact info has been passed on to them and they may contact you if they have questions about the repair."

            SmtpMail.Send(oMailMsg)
            oMailMsg.Dispose()
        End Using
    End Using
End If

And the text is received as:
1 of 3
FRM:programs@email.com
SUBJ:Your Surfboard Repair Has Been Picked Up
MSG:This message is to notify you that the board you dropped
(Con't) 2 of 3
off for repair has been picked up by the repairman. Your contact info has been passed on to them and they may contact you if they have
(Con't) 3 of 3
questions about the repair.

This is quite confusing to read. It's all one text message... Is there something going on with the mail buffer that's splitting the message up as it sends? Is there a way to get this to send as one full message instead of 3 parts?
I've poked around the available options under MailMessage and SmptClient, but haven't found anything that looks like a buffer size. I already switched IsBodyHtml between true and false, this didn't change anything.
-Edit-
Modifying the message body to include HTML doesn't help either, the phone completely ignores the formatting, <br/> doesn't even leave a space, and it it still getting broken up into 3 parts.

For phones, "text message" usually means SMS. Are you trying to send information via some sort of email-to-SMS bridge? Have you tried simply using email?

@AndrewMorton The program uses textboxes and checkboxes to optionally notify you by email or text message, so both are required. And no I'm not using any third party software or bridge, this solution is free, It's just a normal smtp sent email to a phonenumber@phoneprovider.text.email.com

Is there any budget for using a proper SMS gateway service? Can you successfully send the message from an ordinary mail client?

@AndrewMorton There is no budget yet, we are a small business and we try to be frugal when we can... do you mean from outlook or thunderbird? I just gave that a try and ended up with the same result. It sends, but if it's longer than 120 characters (From + Subject + Message) it gets split apart. I suppose that rules out a programming problem...

The following may be of interest: SMS Character Limit and How to send a text from email using iPhone, Verizon, and more. If you don't live in the U.S., then you'll have to find the information for the carriers in your country.

The SMS Character Limit seems to be what I'm hitting... Knowing what terms to search for is half the battle... If you'd like to include that in an official answer, and a simple suggestion for dealing with it, I'll accept it. The second link is very similar to what I used with the table of gateway domains and comes up easily with a search for 'email to text'. If the question is still unanswered when I get my final solution working, I'll answer with what I did.

You haven't specified which carrier that you are attempting to send the message to, but you may try sending to the MMS address instead of the SMS address if your carrier has one. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with how to compose an MMS message.

The carrier varies by customer. I can't guarantee that all of my customers use the same carrier, so I have a combobox to pick from the known carriers so I can append the email ending to their phone number according to the email-to-text table. Some carriers have both and the table shows that too. I'm not planning to send images or anything, so SMS should suffice. I was just unaware of some of the limitations and specific terms used for newer technology.

Just to test, in line with @AndrewMorton's helpful comment, I sent the same message to my phone with the MMS email instead of the SMS email from Thunderbird and the message arrived unbroken and formatted a bit better. Since not all carriers support it I should still fall back to the SMS version for those carriers and account for the limitations therein.

With help from Andrew and user246821 in their comments, I was able to determine that my problem wasn't in my code, or a missed step with sending the message. So if anyone wants to send a text message to a phone through an email my code works just fine, as long as you fill in the 10 digit phone number and correct email ending from the phone provider table.
The character limit is a limitation of the SMS platform, which is what my emails were sending to, however in the phone provider table most carriers support MMS now which is newer and doesn't have the same limits. So for now, if supported, I am using each phone provider's MMS email to send the text messages. If this part of our business expands later and we need to send more than short quick updates we will look into a paid service like Twillio or Constant Contact.
